# Unifrom circular motion along the horizontal plane

Tags: kinematics, vectors, relative-motion

Imagine that a person is walking with a constant velocity along the horizontal plane and
turns the fan on the filing into a circular motion. Then, after sometime the fan will achieve a constant velocity, Then derive a relation to know the relative velocity of the fan with respect to that person! Say the radius of the fan is r, the acceleration is a,
and the constant velocity achieved by the fan is v in time t.